# Git merging another fork

Tags: git, github

Ok so I have my own fork of a project and someone else has their own version of the project. What is the easiest way to merge the files of the two forks without having to merge or send a pull request with the Master that we both forked from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull it from the fork:

```
git pull URL branchname
```